# Bootstrap Tooltip Behavior Not Occurring All The Time, Likely Due to Turbolinks

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, turbolinks

I am using Rails 4.  I pulled in only the Bootstrap javascript and css for tooltips via Bootstrap's [customize tool](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/).

I notice that when I make a *direct* request to a page (typing in url and pressing enter) the tooltip javascript effect works just fine.  However: if I navigate to the page via clicking a link, or click the back button to go to the page with the tooltip: the tooltip effect no longer works.

I am confident turbolinks is messing this up, but after many attempts I have not been successful in fixing the issue.  Removing turbolinks from the app is not an option.

I call the tooltip like so:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray for tooltips!"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Here is the relevant js files:

**assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require bootstrap_tooltip
//= require_self
//= require turbolinks

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

---

**assets/javascripts/bootstrap_tooltip.js** file.

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

/*!
 * Generated using the Bootstrap Customizer (http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=63028410c15050ebe29d01d3064c7189)
 * Config saved to config.json and https://gist.github.com/63028410c15050ebe29d01d3064c7189
 */




    if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
        throw new Error('Bootstrap\'s JavaScript requires jQuery')
    }
    +function ($) {
        'use strict';
        var version = $.fn.jquery.split(' ')[0].split('.')
        if ((version[0] < 2 && version[1] < 9) || (version[0] == 1 && version[1] == 9 && version[2] < 1) || (version[0] > 3)) {
            throw new Error('Bootstrap\'s JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4')
        }
    }(jQuery);

    /* ========================================================================
     * Bootstrap: tooltip.js v3.3.7
     * http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltip
     * Inspired by the original jQuery.tipsy by Jason Frame
     * ========================================================================
     * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
     * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
     * ======================================================================== */


    +function ($) {
        'use strict';

        // TOOLTIP PUBLIC CLASS DEFINITION
        // ===============================

        var Tooltip = function (element, options) {
            this.type       = null
            this.options    = null
            this.enabled    = null
            this.timeout    = null
            this.hoverState = null
            this.$element   = null
            this.inState    = null

            this.init('tooltip', element, options)
        }

        Tooltip.VERSION  = '3.3.7'

        Tooltip.TRANSITION_DURATION = 150

        Tooltip.DEFAULTS = {
            animation: true,
            placement: 'top',
            selector: false,
            template: '<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>',
            trigger: 'hover focus',
            title: '',
            delay: 0,
            html: false,
            container: false,
            viewport: {
                selector: 'body',
                padding: 0
            }
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.init = function (type, element, options) {
            this.enabled   = true
            this.type      = type
            this.$element  = $(element)
            this.options   = this.getOptions(options)
            this.$viewport = this.options.viewport && $($.isFunction(this.options.viewport) ? this.options.viewport.call(this, this.$element) : (this.options.viewport.selector || this.options.viewport))
            this.inState   = { click: false, hover: false, focus: false }

            if (this.$element[0] instanceof document.constructor && !this.options.selector) {
                throw new Error('`selector` option must be specified when initializing ' + this.type + ' on the window.document object!')
            }

            var triggers = this.options.trigger.split(' ')

            for (var i = triggers.length; i--;) {
                var trigger = triggers[i]

                if (trigger == 'click') {
                    this.$element.on('click.' + this.type, this.options.selector, $.proxy(this.toggle, this))
                } else if (trigger != 'manual') {
                    var eventIn  = trigger == 'hover' ? 'mouseenter' : 'focusin'
                    var eventOut = trigger == 'hover' ? 'mouseleave' : 'focusout'

                    this.$element.on(eventIn  + '.' + this.type, this.options.selector, $.proxy(this.enter, this))
                    this.$element.on(eventOut + '.' + this.type, this.options.selector, $.proxy(this.leave, this))
                }
            }

            this.options.selector ?
                (this._options = $.extend({}, this.options, { trigger: 'manual', selector: '' })) :
                this.fixTitle()
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.getDefaults = function () {
            return Tooltip.DEFAULTS
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.getOptions = function (options) {
            options = $.extend({}, this.getDefaults(), this.$element.data(), options)

            if (options.delay && typeof options.delay == 'number') {
                options.delay = {
                    show: options.delay,
                    hide: options.delay
                }
            }

            return options
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.getDelegateOptions = function () {
            var options  = {}
            var defaults = this.getDefaults()

            this._options && $.each(this._options, function (key, value) {
                if (defaults[key] != value) options[key] = value
            })

            return options
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.enter = function (obj) {
            var self = obj instanceof this.constructor ?
                obj : $(obj.currentTarget).data('bs.' + this.type)

            if (!self) {
                self = new this.constructor(obj.currentTarget, this.getDelegateOptions())
                $(obj.currentTarget).data('bs.' + this.type, self)
            }

            if (obj instanceof $.Event) {
                self.inState[obj.type == 'focusin' ? 'focus' : 'hover'] = true
            }

            if (self.tip().hasClass('in') || self.hoverState == 'in') {
                self.hoverState = 'in'
                return
            }

            clearTimeout(self.timeout)

            self.hoverState = 'in'

            if (!self.options.delay || !self.options.delay.show) return self.show()

            self.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                if (self.hoverState == 'in') self.show()
            }, self.options.delay.show)
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.isInStateTrue = function () {
            for (var key in this.inState) {
                if (this.inState[key]) return true
            }

            return false
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.leave = function (obj) {
            var self = obj instanceof this.constructor ?
                obj : $(obj.currentTarget).data('bs.' + this.type)

            if (!self) {
                self = new this.constructor(obj.currentTarget, this.getDelegateOptions())
                $(obj.currentTarget).data('bs.' + this.type, self)
            }

            if (obj instanceof $.Event) {
                self.inState[obj.type == 'focusout' ? 'focus' : 'hover'] = false
            }

            if (self.isInStateTrue()) return

            clearTimeout(self.timeout)

            self.hoverState = 'out'

            if (!self.options.delay || !self.options.delay.hide) return self.hide()

            self.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                if (self.hoverState == 'out') self.hide()
            }, self.options.delay.hide)
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.show = function () {
            var e = $.Event('show.bs.' + this.type)

            if (this.hasContent() && this.enabled) {
                this.$element.trigger(e)

                var inDom = $.contains(this.$element[0].ownerDocument.documentElement, this.$element[0])
                if (e.isDefaultPrevented() || !inDom) return
                var that = this

                var $tip = this.tip()

                var tipId = this.getUID(this.type)

                this.setContent()
                $tip.attr('id', tipId)
                this.$element.attr('aria-describedby', tipId)

                if (this.options.animation) $tip.addClass('fade')

                var placement = typeof this.options.placement == 'function' ?
                    this.options.placement.call(this, $tip[0], this.$element[0]) :
                    this.options.placement

                var autoToken = /\s?auto?\s?/i
                var autoPlace = autoToken.test(placement)
                if (autoPlace) placement = placement.replace(autoToken, '') || 'top'

                $tip
                    .detach()
                    .css({ top: 0, left: 0, display: 'block' })
                    .addClass(placement)
                    .data('bs.' + this.type, this)

                this.options.container ? $tip.appendTo(this.options.container) : $tip.insertAfter(this.$element)
                this.$element.trigger('inserted.bs.' + this.type)

                var pos          = this.getPosition()
                var actualWidth  = $tip[0].offsetWidth
                var actualHeight = $tip[0].offsetHeight

                if (autoPlace) {
                    var orgPlacement = placement
                    var viewportDim = this.getPosition(this.$viewport)

                    placement = placement == 'bottom' && pos.bottom + actualHeight > viewportDim.bottom ? 'top'    :
                        placement == 'top'    && pos.top    - actualHeight < viewportDim.top    ? 'bottom' :
                            placement == 'right'  && pos.right  + actualWidth  > viewportDim.width  ? 'left'   :
                                placement == 'left'   && pos.left   - actualWidth  < viewportDim.left   ? 'right'  :
                                    placement

                    $tip
                        .removeClass(orgPlacement)
                        .addClass(placement)
                }

                var calculatedOffset = this.getCalculatedOffset(placement, pos, actualWidth, actualHeight)

                this.applyPlacement(calculatedOffset, placement)

                var complete = function () {
                    var prevHoverState = that.hoverState
                    that.$element.trigger('shown.bs.' + that.type)
                    that.hoverState = null

                    if (prevHoverState == 'out') that.leave(that)
                }

                $.support.transition && this.$tip.hasClass('fade') ?
                    $tip
                        .one('bsTransitionEnd', complete)
                        .emulateTransitionEnd(Tooltip.TRANSITION_DURATION) :
                    complete()
            }
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.applyPlacement = function (offset, placement) {
            var $tip   = this.tip()
            var width  = $tip[0].offsetWidth
            var height = $tip[0].offsetHeight

            // manually read margins because getBoundingClientRect includes difference
            var marginTop = parseInt($tip.css('margin-top'), 10)
            var marginLeft = parseInt($tip.css('margin-left'), 10)

            // we must check for NaN for ie 8/9
            if (isNaN(marginTop))  marginTop  = 0
            if (isNaN(marginLeft)) marginLeft = 0

            offset.top  += marginTop
            offset.left += marginLeft

            // $.fn.offset doesn't round pixel values
            // so we use setOffset directly with our own function B-0
            $.offset.setOffset($tip[0], $.extend({
                using: function (props) {
                    $tip.css({
                        top: Math.round(props.top),
                        left: Math.round(props.left)
                    })
                }
            }, offset), 0)

            $tip.addClass('in')

            // check to see if placing tip in new offset caused the tip to resize itself
            var actualWidth  = $tip[0].offsetWidth
            var actualHeight = $tip[0].offsetHeight

            if (placement == 'top' && actualHeight != height) {
                offset.top = offset.top + height - actualHeight
            }

            var delta = this.getViewportAdjustedDelta(placement, offset, actualWidth, actualHeight)

            if (delta.left) offset.left += delta.left
            else offset.top += delta.top

            var isVertical          = /top|bottom/.test(placement)
            var arrowDelta          = isVertical ? delta.left * 2 - width + actualWidth : delta.top * 2 - height + actualHeight
            var arrowOffsetPosition = isVertical ? 'offsetWidth' : 'offsetHeight'

            $tip.offset(offset)
            this.replaceArrow(arrowDelta, $tip[0][arrowOffsetPosition], isVertical)
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.replaceArrow = function (delta, dimension, isVertical) {
            this.arrow()
                .css(isVertical ? 'left' : 'top', 50 * (1 - delta / dimension) + '%')
                .css(isVertical ? 'top' : 'left', '')
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.setContent = function () {
            var $tip  = this.tip()
            var title = this.getTitle()

            $tip.find('.tooltip-inner')[this.options.html ? 'html' : 'text'](title)
            $tip.removeClass('fade in top bottom left right')
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.hide = function (callback) {
            var that = this
            var $tip = $(this.$tip)
            var e    = $.Event('hide.bs.' + this.type)

            function complete() {
                if (that.hoverState != 'in') $tip.detach()
                if (that.$element) { // TODO: Check whether guarding this code with this `if` is really necessary.
                    that.$element
                        .removeAttr('aria-describedby')
                        .trigger('hidden.bs.' + that.type)
                }
                callback && callback()
            }

            this.$element.trigger(e)

            if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

            $tip.removeClass('in')

            $.support.transition && $tip.hasClass('fade') ?
                $tip
                    .one('bsTransitionEnd', complete)
                    .emulateTransitionEnd(Tooltip.TRANSITION_DURATION) :
                complete()

            this.hoverState = null

            return this
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.fixTitle = function () {
            var $e = this.$element
            if ($e.attr('title') || typeof $e.attr('data-original-title') != 'string') {
                $e.attr('data-original-title', $e.attr('title') || '').attr('title', '')
            }
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.hasContent = function () {
            return this.getTitle()
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.getPosition = function ($element) {
            $element   = $element || this.$element

            var el     = $element[0]
            var isBody = el.tagName == 'BODY'

            var elRect    = el.getBoundingClientRect()
            if (elRect.width == null) {
                // width and height are missing in IE8, so compute them manually; see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14093
                elRect = $.extend({}, elRect, { width: elRect.right - elRect.left, height: elRect.bottom - elRect.top })
            }
            var isSvg = window.SVGElement && el instanceof window.SVGElement
            // Avoid using $.offset() on SVGs since it gives incorrect results in jQuery 3.
            // See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20280
            var elOffset  = isBody ? { top: 0, left: 0 } : (isSvg ? null : $element.offset())
            var scroll    = { scroll: isBody ? document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop : $element.scrollTop() }
            var outerDims = isBody ? { width: $(window).width(), height: $(window).height() } : null

            return $.extend({}, elRect, scroll, outerDims, elOffset)
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.getCalculatedOffset = function (placement, pos, actualWidth, actualHeight) {
            return placement == 'bottom' ? { top: pos.top + pos.height,   left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth / 2 } :
                placement == 'top'    ? { top: pos.top - actualHeight, left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth / 2 } :
                    placement == 'left'   ? { top: pos.top + pos.height / 2 - actualHeight / 2, left: pos.left - actualWidth } :
                        /* placement == 'right' */ { top: pos.top + pos.height / 2 - actualHeight / 2, left: pos.left + pos.width }

        }

        Tooltip.prototype.getViewportAdjustedDelta = function (placement, pos, actualWidth, actualHeight) {
            var delta = { top: 0, left: 0 }
            if (!this.$viewport) return delta

            var viewportPadding = this.options.viewport && this.options.viewport.padding || 0
            var viewportDimensions = this.getPosition(this.$viewport)

            if (/right|left/.test(placement)) {
                var topEdgeOffset    = pos.top - viewportPadding - viewportDimensions.scroll
                var bottomEdgeOffset = pos.top + viewportPadding - viewportDimensions.scroll + actualHeight
                if (topEdgeOffset < viewportDimensions.top) { // top overflow
                    delta.top = viewportDimensions.top - topEdgeOffset
                } else if (bottomEdgeOffset > viewportDimensions.top + viewportDimensions.height) { // bottom overflow
                    delta.top = viewportDimensions.top + viewportDimensions.height - bottomEdgeOffset
                }
            } else {
                var leftEdgeOffset  = pos.left - viewportPadding
                var rightEdgeOffset = pos.left + viewportPadding + actualWidth
                if (leftEdgeOffset < viewportDimensions.left) { // left overflow
                    delta.left = viewportDimensions.left - leftEdgeOffset
                } else if (rightEdgeOffset > viewportDimensions.right) { // right overflow
                    delta.left = viewportDimensions.left + viewportDimensions.width - rightEdgeOffset
                }
            }

            return delta
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.getTitle = function () {
            var title
            var $e = this.$element
            var o  = this.options

            title = $e.attr('data-original-title')
                || (typeof o.title == 'function' ? o.title.call($e[0]) :  o.title)

            return title
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.getUID = function (prefix) {
            do prefix += ~~(Math.random() * 1000000)
            while (document.getElementById(prefix))
            return prefix
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.tip = function () {
            if (!this.$tip) {
                this.$tip = $(this.options.template)
                if (this.$tip.length != 1) {
                    throw new Error(this.type + ' `template` option must consist of exactly 1 top-level element!')
                }
            }
            return this.$tip
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.arrow = function () {
            return (this.$arrow = this.$arrow || this.tip().find('.tooltip-arrow'))
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.enable = function () {
            this.enabled = true
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.disable = function () {
            this.enabled = false
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.toggleEnabled = function () {
            this.enabled = !this.enabled
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.toggle = function (e) {
            var self = this
            if (e) {
                self = $(e.currentTarget).data('bs.' + this.type)
                if (!self) {
                    self = new this.constructor(e.currentTarget, this.getDelegateOptions())
                    $(e.currentTarget).data('bs.' + this.type, self)
                }
            }

            if (e) {
                self.inState.click = !self.inState.click
                if (self.isInStateTrue()) self.enter(self)
                else self.leave(self)
            } else {
                self.tip().hasClass('in') ? self.leave(self) : self.enter(self)
            }
        }

        Tooltip.prototype.destroy = function () {
            var that = this
            clearTimeout(this.timeout)
            this.hide(function () {
                that.$element.off('.' + that.type).removeData('bs.' + that.type)
                if (that.$tip) {
                    that.$tip.detach()
                }
                that.$tip = null
                that.$arrow = null
                that.$viewport = null
                that.$element = null
            })
        }


        // TOOLTIP PLUGIN DEFINITION
        // =========================

        function Plugin(option) {
            return this.each(function () {
                var $this   = $(this)
                var data    = $this.data('bs.tooltip')
                var options = typeof option == 'object' && option

                if (!data && /destroy|hide/.test(option)) return
                if (!data) $this.data('bs.tooltip', (data = new Tooltip(this, options)))
                if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
            })
        }

        var old = $.fn.tooltip

        $.fn.tooltip             = Plugin
        $.fn.tooltip.Constructor = Tooltip


        // TOOLTIP NO CONFLICT
        // ===================

        $.fn.tooltip.noConflict = function () {
            $.fn.tooltip = old
            return this
        }

    }(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 8):

Appears I got it to work.  Within `assets/javascripts/application.js` I changed this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

To this:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
})
```